# pack() won't pack right

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, layout-manager

I have a JFrame here:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Game extends JFrame {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7919358146481096788L;
    Arena a = new Arena();
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Game();
    }
    private Game() {
        setTitle("Insert name of game here");
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setLayout(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        add(a);
        pack();
        setResizable(false);
        setVisible(true);
    }
    private void refresh() {

    }
}
```

And the `Arena` is a JPanel:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Arena extends JPanel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6499922741928110264L;
    byte[][] world = new byte[6000][2000];
    int blockPix = 20;
    int x = 2999 * blockPix, y = 999 * blockPix;
    public Arena() {
        setLayout(null);
        setMinimumSize(new Dimension(600, 600));
        setMaximumSize(new Dimension(600, 600));
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 600));
    }
}
```

Yet the JFrame's size winds up being 0 by 0!

Comment: If you remove the `pack()` call, does it work?

Comment: **Do not** use a null layout manager--**EVER**!

Comment: why not? I always do. this is a game.

Comment: See: [Why is it frowned upon to use a null layout in Swing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6592468/why-is-it-frowned-upon-to-use-a-null-layout-in-swing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should remove the instruction `setLayout(null);` in the `Game` constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could just `setSize(600, 600);` where you are doing all the other fixing up in your constructor?

Comment: no, because the title bar of the frame and all of the decorations are included and it just doesn't work.